# How to pass result of async functon to Angular template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have async function permission() that works fine, but I don't know how to pass the result of this function to angular template.

I have this code it .ts file:

```
async havePermission(channelId) {
        console.log('is private' + ' ' + await this.isPrivateChannel2(channelId));
        console.log('in channel' + ' ' + await this.inChannel(channelId));
        if (await this.isPrivateChannel2(channelId) && !(await this.inChannel(channelId))) {
            console.log('no permission');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('have permission');
            return true;
        }
    }

    async permission(channelId) {
        return await this.havePermission(channelId);
    }
}
```

And this is a part of my template:

```
<app-chat *ngIf="permission(channelId)" [channelId]="channelId"></app-chat>
```

app-chat component always shows, even if permission returns false, why?

Comment: Check the `async` pipe

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: Well, could you post the code where you use the pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bind the result of that `promise` (or any async operation, Observables too) to your template you need to use the `async` pipe, like:

```
<app-chat *ngIf="permission(channelId) | async" [channelId]="channelId"></app-chat>
```

For further information you can check the documentation:

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I have one problem. I added console.log() in permission function. When I try to delete channel `this.channelId = channel.$key;
this.channels.remove(this.channelId);` I have hundreds and thousands of console.log() and my browser just freezes.

Comment: Precisely, that's because of the change detection in angular

Comment: Yeah, it seems, but I don't know what I have to change to make it work.

Comment: I don't intend to be rude, but maybe you should ask another question, that way your problem will have much more exposure.